# Mirror X in Blender 2.8

Tags: mirror

Is the 'X Mirror' option under the 'Mesh Options' working in 2.8 Beta? It appears to do nothing at the moment. Or am I doing something wrong? Simply enabling it on the default cube doesn't allow me to move one vertex and have the other vertex on the X axis move.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about issues with experimental development versions of Blender

Comment: Baffles me also? 2.79+ has it, and I use it during rigging. So useful, I can't use 2.8 currently for rig design?? Anybody else??